# SSRS Visual Studio 2017 - hide extra rows in a group

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I am new to the SSRS and I am having this issue with the empty rows in a group on my report.

This is the report design. The last column is hidden.

[image]

And this is the sample data. There is an extra empty row.

[image]

As you can see, there is an empty row under the "Standard Issue" and I am trying to hide this empty row. I tried using an expression on the row visibility, but it is still showing.

```
=iif(Fields!IssueReason.Value is nothing, false, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The visibility property is actually a "hidden" property, you your expression needs to be reversed. You can just use

```
 =Fields!IssueReason.Value is nothing
```

as this will return true if the value is nothing.

If this does not help, edit your question to show your report design including you row groups and some sample data fro your dataset.

Comment: you'll need to show what the data looks like when it comes from your dataset, the query output. Also show you row and column group panels.